# How to use PercentRelativeLayout in API 25

Tags: android, android-percentrelativelayout

I want to use **PercentRelativeLayout** but I have the **compileSdkVersion 25**.
Which dependency should I add to build.grade(Module: app)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the dependency for `PercentRelativeLayout`

**compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.0.0'**

Answer (score 1):

add this in your `build.grade(Module: app)` dependencies

```
apply plugin:
   {
   .
   .
   .
   .
   }
dependencies {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.1.1'

}
```